# Choosing a compact c/c++ compiler for ARM based Embedded Linux System

Tags: linux, embedded

I am working on ARM cortex A7 based embedded system that runs Linux. I am looking for c/c++ compiler (as GCC is around 100 mb) which is compact in size and reliable. I have shortlisted some as SDCC, TCC, OTCC, Digital Mars, NWCC, LCC, Small C, portable C compiler.

I want to know if compilers are dependent on operating system or hardware and how should I proceed to start strip down the list. I am not an expert and I am learning about Linux systems and embedded environment. If you think I am asking wrong question or going in wrong direction, Kindly let me know.

Thanks you

Note

I already have cross compiler on my linux (laptop) system. I compile program to be loaded using this only. But the embedded system is supposed to be able to load with a particular language designed by us, I am hoping to convert that language in to equivalent C code and run it. I tried writing my own interpreter in c that accepts the code in other language and parse it and executes but it's little slow, I tried same instructions in (directly written in) C with satisfactory results.

Edit:
I ended up using g++ on my system to compile code, as main function of system was to use generated code.

Comment: Why do you need a small compiler?  Are you planning on running it on the embedded target itself?  Why does your embedded system need to compile stuff?

Comment: The embedded system is supposed to be able to load with a particular language designed by us, I am hoping to convert that language in to equivalent C code. I tried writing my own interpreter but it's little slow, I tried same instructions in C with satisfactory results. That's why.

Comment: Maybe you would be better off to use a lightweight scripting language specifically designed for embedding, like LUA?

Comment: I tried LUA, results were satisfactory, but I am planning to consider and compare all possible options before making the decision.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, when dealing with embedded systems you are better off cross-compiling and sending the binaries than compiling directly on the device. Even though it may consume you some time setting up the toolchain on the beginning, it definitely pays you back with build time.

There are several pre-built Linaro GCC which are cross-compilers having (generally) x86 linux as host and arm linux as target platforms. This way, you should not worry about compiler size.

Comment: The embedded system is supposed to be able to load with a particular language designed by us, I am hoping to convert that language in to equivalent C code. I tried writing my own interpreter but it's little slow, I tried same instructions in C with satisfactory results. That's why I need compiler on embedded system

Comment: I think you should define a more lightweight language.

Comment: @dwelch I didn't quit understand, can you explain please.

Comment: As far as I understand, you should write and cross compile an interpreter and send its binaries into the embedded system. There, you use it to read your language scripts or even to compile there. The point is the C compiler does not need to be embedded. Please, let me know if I misunderstood something.

Comment: see all of the above, it sounds like you have painted yourself into a corner if you require something as complex as a C compiler into a system that doesnt have room.  Most of the compilers you mentioned simply will not work, the ones that will sounds like you dont have the room for.   You are saying you wanted to basically compile from one language to C then download it you might as well compile it all the way rather than overly complicate it into a language translation to be re-compiled.  I assume you probably dont have the room to have the defined language be assembly language

Comment: because of all the libraries you would have to carry around.  your problem is very very simple, boost the capabilities of the embedded system to meet your C language requirements or get rid of the requirements that dont meet your resources (perhaps get rid of linux and certainly get rid of C).

Comment: @Heits the interpreter was very slow, LUA is my better option than that, I just wanted to check ups and downs of other option i.e. c compiler.

Comment: @dwelch The system has a Apache server that provides web interface to upload code and other administration work on system, system runs uploaded code in background continuously and sends input/outputs through Ethernet and serial ports. The system has 256 mb flash and there's enough space left for compiler but I am going to decide if wasting more space for faster execution is worth it, once I know how much space I am going to need. I want to decide after I have most of the info.

Comment: apache server you could use javascript, etc as your download language perhaps, php, etc, something you may have already installed.  You could take other interpreted approaches like compile java to bytecode or python to bytecode or llvm to bytecode and on the embedded system only have the virtual machine and not the whole compiler...

Comment: The user who log on in to system supposed to upload code in a particular developed language (designed as per user convince) by just using Internet browser. So there's nowhere else to compile. So far Lua is best bet, but I need to know which compiler can work and how much space will it need.

Comment: That's much better now. Anyway, just because users will upload only the code, it doesn't mean you need a compiler on your system. There are very lightweight lua interpreters which you can use. I cannot tell you about their performance as I have never looked deeper into it. AFAIK, there are also very lightwight python interpreters which you could make use of.